# How did these mysterious meta tags get into my Weebly site?

Tags: html, templates, weebly

The Weebly templates for my site do not match what I see on the actual website.  Specifically, I am seeing meta tags in the document head which I did not add there:

```html
<meta property="og:site_name" content="..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
```

I've checked through all templates, made sure that javascript is not inserting them, etc.  What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The weebly backend makes many modifications to site's html code which are not reflected in the site's templates.  For example, they insert the lang attribute into the html tag if you have a site language set:
`<html>` ➡ `<html lang="de">`

Weebly also inserts the above `<meta>` tags and the `<title>` tag based on your site's content.  Presumably this is meant to help inexperienced site developers.

Weebly templates offer a *general* outline of what you want in your site, rather than an explicit code template as you might expect in Django, PHP, etc.  Much is still controlled by Weebly.